# Rotation of two parabola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

> Let a circle $C:x^2+y^2=1$ and two parabolas $P_1:y^2=4(x-1)$ and $P_2:y^2=-4(x+1)$
>
> Both parabolas slides on the circle towards each other with same angular velocity such that they are tangent to circle and their axis are normal to circle after $9$ minutes
>
> They get coincident first time, then:
>
> If $P_1$ and $P_2$ intersect each other during their rotation then their point of intersection lies on $(x\neq 0)$
>
> A) $4x^2+y^4+8y^2=0$
>
> B) $4x^2+y^4+4y^2=0$
>
> C) $8x^2+y^4+8y^2=0$
>
> D) $8x^2+y^4+4y^2=0$

In this I could not get a good start .

And by seeing the options, I thought how this can be possible as in LHS everything is positive and it is equated to zero

([Original Question Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDoFi.jpg))

Comment: There must be some error: as you noticed, all four equations have only $(0,0)$ as solution.

Comment: @Aretino by the way answer is given as option A

Comment: The point where $P_1$ and $P_2$ touch for the first time is $(0,2\sqrt2)$, which lies on the circle of equation $x^2+y^2=8$. I suppose this equation could have been the right solution.

Comment: @Aretino how you found that

Comment: Because lines $y=\pm x$ are tangent to $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: @Aretino how can we say intersection of these lines is intersection of parabola . There can be many tangents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blue parabolas in the diagram are $P_1$ and $P_2$. They touch red lines $y=\pm x$ at points $(\pm2,\pm2)$.

After a $45°$ rotation, they will arrive at the position of the green parabolas in the diagram, line $x=0$ touching both at $(0,2\sqrt2)$.

[image]